# Check if there's an error in IDataErrorInfo after button clicked

Tags: wpf, mvvm, idataerrorinfo

I am using IDataErrorInfo to validate my fields, the binding of fields and showing of errors are all working correctly. But I don't know how can the SaveButton know if there's an error in the fields? Currently I found a work around for this. But I'm sure there's a better way to do this.

Here's some part of my codes that I think you need to see to help me with this:

Model:

```
public TransactionModel : IDataErrorInfo
{
    public enum Field
    {
        Col1, 
        Col2
        Col3,
        //...
    };

    public List<Field> Errors = new List<Field>();

    public string Error { get { throw new NotImplementedException(); } }

    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            string result = string.Empty;
            switch (columnName)
            {
                case "col1":
                    //validation goes here
                    if (errors found)
                    {
                        result = "error message";
                        Errors.Add(Field.Col1);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result = string.Empty;
                        if (Errors.Exists(x => x == Field.Col1))
                            Errors.Remove(Field.Col1);
                    }
                    break;
                case "col2":
                    //validation goes here
                    if (errors found)
                    {
                        result = "error message";
                        Errors.Add(Field.Col2);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result = string.Empty;
                        if (Errors.Exists(x => x == Field.Col2))
                            Errors.Remove(Field.Col2);
                    }
                    break;
                case "col3":
                    //etc....
                return result;
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

View:

```
<Button Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" Content="Save"/>
```

ViewModel:

```
public ICommand SaveCommand
{
    get { return new DelegateCommand(Save); }
}

private void Save()
{
    if (Transaction.Errors.Count <= 0)
    {
        //save transaction routine goes here
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please correct the errors in red", "Error");
    }
}
```

THanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 1):

You should change implementation of Error property to this:

```
public string Error
{
    get { return this[null]; }
}
```

And then add another property for simplicity:

```
public bool IsValid 
{
   get { return string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Error); }
}
```